# How to update particular value inside array - Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection Users that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23"),
    "contact" : {
        "firstName" : "Mark",
        "lastName" : "Doe",
        "parentsBloodType" : [ 
            {
                "type" : "AB+",
            }, 
            {
                "type" : "A+",
            }, 
        ],
    },
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-10-31T07:13:11.278Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-11-26T09:59:41.611Z")
}
```

I need to run a raw query to update from AB+ to O-. I would also like to check if they match before updating.

I tried this but it added an extra field to the User:

```
  db.getCollection('users').update(
    {"_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23")},
    {"$set" : { 'parentsBloodType.' + '0' + '. type' : "O-"}}
    )
```

Comment: What happens if both parents have `AB+`? Do you like to update both or just one?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I would like to update both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one would do the update:

```
db.users.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23") },
   { "$set": { 'contact.parentsBloodType.0.type' : "O-"} }
)
```

You an check match with this:

```
db.users.update(
   {
      "_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23"),
      "contact.parentsBloodType.type": "AB+"
   },
   { "$set": { 'contact.parentsBloodType.0.type': "AB+" } }
)
```

This updates the document only if type `AB+` exist (at any parent).

Or if you like to check whether the **first** type is `AB+` then use

```
db.users.update(
   {
      "_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23"),
      "contact.parentsBloodType.0.type": "AB+"
   },
   { "$set": { 'contact.parentsBloodType.0.type': "AB+" } }
)
```

However, I assume you are actually looking for this:

```
db.users.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23") },
   { "$set": { 'contact.parentsBloodType.$[p].type': "0-" } },
   { arrayFilters: [{ "p.type": "AB+" }] }
)
```

Which will update any `AB+` to `0-` no matter on which position it appears in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the positional $ operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) to update **the first element** that matches the query document:

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
  { "_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23"), "parentsBloodType.type": "AB+" },
  { "$set" : { 'parentsBloodType.$.type' : "O-" } }
)
```

note that:

> - the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the **first element** that matches the query document, and
> - **the array field must appear** as part of the query document.

Or use [the filtered positional operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E]) if you want to update all elements that match an array filter condition or conditions:

```
db.students.update(
   { "_id": ObjectId("5dba8987b4a39c13bc104a23") },
   { $set: { "parentsBloodType.$[element].type" : "O-" } },
   { 
     arrayFilters: [ { "element.type": "AB+" } ]
   }
)
```

Comment: Just a note, `multi: true` means update multiple documents - not update multiple values of an array. I.e. regardless of `multi: true` or `multi: false` it will update all matching values in the array. Acctually when you filter on primary key `_id: ObjectId(...)` then `multi: true` is pointless.